# disable button of each package against a value in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I have a package for packages to buy. The packages are showing from the table. I want to do something like when a user purchase a package, after purchasing the package that package's button should be disabled.

My current PHP code:

```php
$userID = $_SESSION['username']['UserID'];
$query = "Select * from tbl_packages";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

foreach ($result as $data) :
    $PkgID = $data['id'];
    $PkgAmount = $data['amount'];
    $PkgFees = $data['fees'];
    $PkgPeriod = $data['period'];
    $ReturningAmount = $data['returnAmount'];
?>

    <!-- The Current HTML Code: -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Package Amount:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $PkgAmount ?></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Return:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $ReturningAmount ?> %</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Returning Days:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $PkgPeriod ?></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $Value ?>
        <div class="col-md-8">Package Fee:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $PkgFees ?> %</span></div>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Confirm befor buy?');" type="submit" id="btn" data-target="#buyPackage" value="Invest" name="bttn-order" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The packages are showing well on the page, but if a user buy an package, the package's button still can be clicked. And I want that to be disabled for active package.

Is that possible in php?

<------------Edited------------>

Package Buy Function with Query:

```php
function ConfirmOrder()
{
    global $conn, $dbUsername, $dbPass, $error;
    $ReturnAmount = e($_POST['PkgRetAmount']);

    $UID = $_SESSION['username']['UserID'];
    $PkgID = e($_POST['PkgID']);
    $LendAmount = e($_POST['PkgAmount']);
    $Fees = e($_POST['PkgFees']);
    $BackAmount = ($LendAmount * $ReturnAmount) / 100;
    $Perdiod = e($_POST['PkgPeriod']);;
    $RemainingDays = $Perdiod;
    $NextTime = "Next Day";
    $Status = 1;

    //$FormAccount = 'location: ../Connection/server.php?ReturnAmount='.$ReturnAmount.'?Fees='.$Fees;
    //header($FormAccount);
    //$msg = "Noman";
    //echo $msg;
    $querySelect = "Select * from tbl_lendinglogs where UserID = '$UID' and pkg_id = '$PkgID' and status = '1'";
    $resultSelect = mysqli_query($conn, $querySelect);
    $numSelect = mysqli_num_rows($resultSelect);
    $FetchedSelect = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSelect);

    if ($numSelect > 0) {
        echo "You already bough this package...!";
    } else {
        $queryInsert = "insert into tbl_lendinglogs (UserID, pkg_id, fees, lend_amount, back_amount, period, remain, next_time, status) values('$UID', '$PkgID', '$Fees', '$LendAmount', '$BackAmount', '$Perdiod', '$RemainingDays', '$NextTime', '$Status')";
        if ($conn->query($queryInsert) == True) {
            echo "Inserted Successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Query Error";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Code where I am showing the packages before purchase on packages page:

```php
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $userID = $_SESSION['username']['UserID'];
    $query = "Select * from tbl_packages";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $pkID = null;
    $Value = null;
    foreach ($result as $dat) {
        $pkID = $dat['id'];
        $queryCheckPackage = "select * from tbl_lendinglogs where UserID = '$userID' and pkg_id = '$pkID'";
        $resultCheckPackage = mysqli_query($conn, $queryCheckPackage);
        $numCheckPackage = mysqli_num_rows($resultCheckPackage);
        $FetchCheckPackage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCheckPackage);

        if ($numCheckPackage > 0) {
            foreach ($resultCheckPackage as $res) {
                if ($res["status"] == 1) {
                    $Value = "disabled";
                } else {
                    $Value = "enabled";
                }
            }
        } else {
            $Value = "enabled";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    foreach ($result as $data) :

        $PkgID = $data['id'];
        $PkgAmount = $data['amount'];
        $PkgFees = $data['fees'];
        $PkgPeriod = $data['period'];
        $ReturningAmount = $data['returnAmount'];
    ?>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card-columns-fluid">
                <div class="card-header text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> <b><span class="badge badge-info"><?php echo $data['title'] ?></span></b></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail mx-auto" style="width:80%;" src="https://image.winudf.com/v2/image/Y29tLmp1dm8ubGVuZGJ0Y19pY29uX2Zxb3BrdjMz/icon.png?w=170&fakeurl=1" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <BR>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">Package Amount:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $PkgAmount ?></span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">Return:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $ReturningAmount ?> %</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">Returning Days:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $PkgPeriod ?></span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-8">Package Fee:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $PkgFees ?> %</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <form action="" class="form-inline" method="POST" id="buyPackage-init">
                            <input class="form-control form-control-user" name="PkgID" id="PackagegID" value=<?php echo $PkgID ?> readonly hidden>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-user" name="PkgFees" id="PackagegPercent" value=<?php echo $PkgFees ?> readonly hidden>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-user" name="PkgAmount" id="PackagegAmount" value=<?php echo $PkgAmount ?> readonly hidden>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-user" name="PkgPeriod" id="PackagegPeriod" value=<?php echo $PkgPeriod ?> readonly hidden>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-user" name="PkgRetAmount" id="PackagegRetAmount" value=<?php echo $ReturningAmount ?> readonly hidden>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Confirm befor buy?');" type="submit" id="btn" data-target="#buyPackage" value="Invest" name="bttn-order" <?php echo $Value ?> />
                    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-order" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buyPackage" id="bttn-order" name="btn-order">Invest</button>-->
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `<input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Confirm befor buy?');" type="submit" id="btn" data-target="#buyPackage" value="Invest" name="bttn-order" />` is the one you wish to disable? `confirm('Confirm befor buy?');` can you post this code as well?

Comment: I've already posted the full code. The button is showing through a loop in the card for each package. And there will be 1 button disabled which is active now for the current user. I just want to disable the button for each package which package is exist in the tbl_packages table against the user.

Comment: Than you do an select and echo that row witch button disabled in php if statement and else with button enabled.

Comment: Where in the table you store that this package is already bought?

Comment: the packages are coming from tbl_packages and then it is storing in tbl_lendinglogs. Can you please show me a little example code? that will really help me to understand. I have tried to do like you said but it is disabling all the buttons but I want to disable the package's button which is store in the table.

Comment: here is my query for selecting: "select * from tbl_lendinglogs where UserID = '$userID' and status = '1' "

Comment: I have written an example in answer in mid time.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't give us much to work on but here goes:

You have to store information that user has already made a purchased of that package somewhere. Lats say in user table in new column. 
After you done that you can before showing that button do a quarry to see if that package id exists in  some column of table user, if result is 0 you echo the normal button if there is a result other then 0 you echo an html code with disabled button or some other information.

**CODE after poster edit with more info:**

```
$userID = $_SESSION['username']['UserID'];
$query = "Select * from tbl_packages";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

foreach ($result as $data) :
    $PkgID = $data['id'];
    $PkgAmount = $data['amount'];
    $PkgFees = $data['fees'];
    $PkgPeriod = $data['period'];
    $ReturningAmount = $data['returnAmount'];
?>

    <!-- The Current HTML Code: -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Package Amount:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $PkgAmount ?></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Return:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $ReturningAmount ?> %</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Returning Days:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $PkgPeriod ?></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $Value ?>
        <div class="col-md-8">Package Fee:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo $PkgFees ?> %</span></div>
    </div>

<?php 
 $query2 = "Select * from tbl_lendinglogs where UserID='$userID' AND pkg_id='$PkgID' AND status = '1'";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
                    echo '
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" onclick="return confirm(\'Confirm befor buy?\');" type="submit" id="btn" data-target="#buyPackage" value="Invest" name="bttn-order" />'
    ; 
                     } else {

               echo '
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" DISABLED  id="btn" data-target="#buyPackage" value="Invest" name="bttn-order" />'
    ;          
 }
 endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. In this way if the condition turns true OR rows count greater than 0 than all the buttons gets disabled. While I want to disable the buttons of packages which are stored in the table against PackageID and UserID.

Comment: Well i made up that SQL query you write your own based on what you need just like you said. I don't see your tables. You mach current user session with package id and if there is a result or isn't you echo corresponding HTML button for that user. I do this all the time for numerous buttons on big tables. Keep in mind my code is made up on blind. I miss way to many parameters but this is a way for you to go.

Comment: of course your code is made up on blind, you are a senior coder to me. Therefore I am asking here for the solution. If you just give a little time, I can show you the tables, but its simple I have two tables one is for to show the packages in a page. and 1 is for to store the package against the user means the user lends the package. after that its simple to set button disable way in a loop, but I don't know how to set it. I just displayed tha packages on the page with foreach loop. But can't use the loop for buttons to disable against the different values.

Comment: Edit your post up and give me a example of how your tables look ill write you and query. I Need to see how you store your info. Where are your pck id's and user 'ids.

Comment: Edited. Please see the edited part. I've included both codes with quries

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically you need to exactly the same thing you are doing on insert, when you check if user has already bought , just this time you echo an wonted button.